# how to change the jquery code from onclick to show content always

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to show a comments section always. Now a user has to click, to start the javascript code to display the content (onclick). a simple change to "onload" is not working. I tried it.

//Show reviews

```
function reviews_show(value) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo site_root?>/members/reviews_content.php',
        data:'id=' + value,
        success:function(data){
            if(document.getElementById('comments_content'))
            {
                document.getElementById('comments_content').innerHTML = data;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

html code on .tpl page:

```
<li><a href="#comments_content" data-toggle="tab" onclick="reviews_show({ID});">Comments</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">

      <div class="tab-pane" id="comments_content"></div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean with always -> on page load -> then this is the answer:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var value='{ID}';     // use value variable for your ID here

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'<?php echo site_root?>/members/reviews_content.php',
        data:'id=' + value,     // or replace to => data:'id={ID}',
        success:function(data){
            if(document.getElementById('comments_content'))
            {
                document.getElementById('comments_content').innerHTML = data;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Of course this was just an example how to make the browser to execute the jQuery.ajax on *Page Loaded Completed*. I edited the code and put the `var value='{ID}'` for your example. Make sure that there is your ID inserted (as it was inserted before in your `onclick="reviews_show({ID});"`.

Comment: it does not fire / nothing happenes

Comment: Difficult to say without the full code but this is the solution, i used it myself many times. put an `alert('test');` inside to see if the DOMContentLoaded Event is firing. Another point is.. `<script src="jquery.."></script>` must be included before this code.. because otherwise jquery is unknown. Make a right click on the page and go to the Developer Tools > Console .. is there any error? Also go to the Network Tab to see if maybe its firing but some other problems exists.

Comment: the code itself worked fine now. I have to rebuild this part of code. The "ids" are selected in another php document. Horrible to change. Thank you anyway.